# How to efficiently resample a Pandas dataframe into 3d NumPy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a big data frame with a `DatetimeIndex` and multiple columns. Now I would like to have an operation `resample_3d` which can be used like this:

```
index, array = df.resample_3d("1h", fill_value=0)
```

... and transforms the data frame

```
index | A | B | C | D
10:00 | 1 |   | 
10:01 | 1 |   | 
12:00 | 1 |   |
13:00 | 1 |   |
```

into a 3d-NumPy array of shape (3, 2, 4). The first dimension is the time (which can be looked up in the separately returned `index`), the second dimension is the row index within the "resample group" and the third dimension are the features. The size of the second dimension is equals the maximum rows in a single resample group. Unused entries are filled (e.g. with zeros).

Is there such a or a similar function in Pandas/another library or is there a way to implement something like this on top of Pandas efficiently without too much work?

I am aware that I could build something on top of `df.resample().apply(list)`, but this is way too slow for bigger data frames.

I have already started my own implementation with Numba, but then quickly realized that this is quite some work.

(I have just discovered xarray and thought I tag this question with it because it may be the better base for doing this than Pandas.)

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what is your data like, but yes, xarray might be what you search for.

Once your data is well-formatted as a [`DataArray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/api.html#dataarray), you can then just do:

```
da.resample(time="1h")
```

It will return a [`DataArrayResample`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.resample.DataArrayResample.html#xarray.core.resample.DataArrayResample) object.

Usually, when resampling, the new coordinates grid doesn't match the previous grid.

Thus, from there, you need to apply one of the numerous [methods of the `DataArrayResample` object](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.resample.DataArrayResample.html#xarray.core.resample.DataArrayResample) to tell xarray how to fill this new grid.

For example, you may want to interpolate values using the original data as knots:

```
da.resample(time="1h").interpolate("linear")
```

But you can also backfill, pad, use the nearest values etc.

If you don't want to fill the new grid, use `.asfreq()` and new times will be set to NaN. You'll still be able to interpolate later using [`interpolate_na()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.interpolate_na.html#xarray.DataArray.interpolate_na).

#### Your case

In your case, it seems that you are doing a down-sampling, and thus that there is an exact match between new grid coordinates and original grid coordinates.

So, methods that will work for you are any of `.nearest()`, `.asfreq()`, `.interpolate()` (note that `.interpolate()` will convert `int` to `float`).

However, since you are downsampling at exact grid knots, what you are really doing is selecting a subset of your array, so you might want to use the [`.sel()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sel.html) method instead.

#### Example

An example of down-sampling on exact grid points knots.

Create the data:

```
>>> dims = ("time", "features")
>>> sizes = (6, 3)
>>> h_step = 0.5

>>> da = xr.DataArray(
        dims=dims,
        data=np.arange(np.prod(sizes)).reshape(*sizes),
        coords=dict(
            time=pd.date_range(
                "04/07/2020",
                periods=sizes[0],
                freq=pd.DateOffset(hours=h_step),
            ),
            features=list(string.ascii_uppercase[: sizes[1]]),
        ),
    )

>>> da
<xarray.DataArray (time: 6, features: 3)>
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-04-07 ... 2020-04-07T02:30:00
  * features  (features) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C'

>>> da.time.values
array(['2020-04-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T00:30:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T01:00:00.000000000', 
       '2020-04-07T01:30:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T02:30:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Downsampling using `.resample()` and `.nearest()`:

```
>>> da.resample(time="1h").nearest()
<xarray.DataArray (time: 3, features: 3)>
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-04-07 ... 2020-04-07T02:00:00
  * features  (features) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C'

>>> da.resample(time="1h").nearest().time.values
array(['2020-04-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T02:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Down-sampling by selection:

```
>>> dwn_step = 2

>>> new_time = pd.date_range(
        "04/07/2020",
        periods=sizes[0] // dwn_step,
        freq=pd.DateOffset(hours=h_step * dwn_step),
    )

>>> da.sel(time=new_time)
<xarray.DataArray (time: 3, features: 3)>
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2020-04-07 ... 2020-04-07T02:00:00
  * features  (features) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C'

>>> da.sel(time=new_time).time.values
array(['2020-04-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-04-07T02:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Another option to create `new_time` index is to merely do:

```
new_time = da.time[::dwn_coeff]
```

It is more straightforward, but you can't choose the first selected time (which can be either good or a bad, depending on your case).

Comment: Yes, but this returns a `DataArrayResample`. It is unclear to me how I could transform this into a 3d-array (except for with apply, which is too slow). The idea is to resample all data into buckets (2nd dimension in example above) without reducing (e.g. mean) it.

Comment: Not all methods to be applied on a `DataArrayResample` object are reducing methods. I added more in-depth explanations, hope it helps.